# Converting String Values into Date using Carbon Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The sql field type is VARCHAR, I am saving date and time from an API. The format that I get is **2018-04-28T22:17:41+05:30**. Now I need to convert this using carbon to get a format like 04 April 2018 and timings. I couldn't convert varchar filed value into date format which I needed.

And the expected format should be passed to view, I did that using ( $ticket->dateOfIssue and it's giving this - 018-04-28T22:17:41+05:30 ). But as I said, I need the expected format (which is 04 April 2018, time ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on your model or set the datetime format on your model. The example of the former is:

```
use Carbon/Carbon; before your class declaration

public function getDateOfIssueAttribute($value) {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d M Y , H:m:s');
}
```

When ever you retrieve this model anywhere you already have it in the format you set in your accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to parse the date

```
Carbon::parse('2018-04-28T22:17:41+05:30')->format('dd MM YYYY');
```

Moreover, do not forget to import the `Carbon` namespaces on the top

Comment: How to use this on controller ?  i am extracting values from database using controller ! `public function cancell()
    {
        $ticket = Booking::all()->where('status', '=', 'CANCELLED');
        return view('Admin.Tickets.cancelledTickets')->with('ticket', $ticket);
    }` ! And then the field name is dateOfIssue from database. Now displaying this to view using `{{ $ticket->dateOfIssue }}`. And there are 120 records. Now how to implement this on controller to automatically parse all the records and display in view ?

Comment: `public function cancell()
    {
        $ticket = Booking::all()->where('status', '=', 'CANCELLED');
        return view('Admin.Tickets.cancelledTickets')->with('ticket', $ticket);
    }` This is my controller code, and the field name from database is dataOfIssue, but its in varchar. So i need to chage this into another format using carbon. And there are 120 record, so this should do automatically so that 120 records in the view shows expected format

Answer (score 0):

You try

```
use use Carbon\Carbon; // on top

$time = Carbon::parse('2018-04-28T22:17:41+05:30')->format('d M Y'); //28 Apr 2018
```

Good luck

Comment: How to use this on controller ?  i am extracting values from database using controller ! `public function cancell()
    {
        $ticket = Booking::all()->where('status', '=', 'CANCELLED');
        return view('Admin.Tickets.cancelledTickets')->with('ticket', $ticket);
    }` ! And then the field name is dateOfIssue from database. Now displaying this to view using `{{ $ticket->dateOfIssue }}`. And there are 120 records. Now how to implement this on controller to automatically parse all the records and display in view ?

Comment: oh,  you use eloquent , you should use Accessors & Mutators. 
link: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators]

        `public function getDateOfIssueAttribute($time) {
            return Carbon::parse($time)->format('d M Y');
        }`
And in view you using `{{ $ticket->dateOfIssue }}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact format for date and time. First of all include carbon library in your controller

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
class abc extend Controller
{
    public function cancell() 
    { 
    $ticket = Booking::all()->where('status', '=', 'CANCELLED');
    $dateOfIssue=$ticket->dateOfIssue;
    $time = Carbon::parse($dateOfIssue)->format('d M Y , H:m:s'); 

    return view('Admin.Tickets.cancelledTickets')->with('ticket', $ticket); 
    }


}
```

If you have multiple records then you can use loop for that

Comment: How to use this on controller ?  i am extracting values from database using controller ! `public function cancell()
    {
        $ticket = Booking::all()->where('status', '=', 'CANCELLED');
        return view('Admin.Tickets.cancelledTickets')->with('ticket', $ticket);
    }` ! And then the field name is dateOfIssue from database. Now displaying this to view using `{{ $ticket->dateOfIssue }}`. And there are 120 records. Now how to implement this on controller to automatically parse all the records and display in view ?

Comment: I am getting an error stating Property [dateOfIssue] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try ,

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2018-04-28T22:17:41+05:30')->format('d- M- Y');
```

the output is 28- Apr- 2018

using sql

```
DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%d-%M-%Y')
```

Comment: How to use this on controller ? i am extracting values from database using controller ! public function cancell() { $ticket = Booking::all()->where('status', '=', 'CANCELLED'); return view('Admin.Tickets.cancelledTickets')->with('ticket', $ticket); } ! And then the field name is dateOfIssue from database. Now displaying this to view using {{ $ticket->dateOfIssue }}. And there are 120 records. Now how to implement this on controller to automatically parse all the records and display in view ?

Comment: @Arvindh then you need to convert the date in sql. I update the answer please check it